# MATLAB: Adding simple GUI to existing complete program

Tags: user-interface, matlab, checkbox

I have spent the last few months working on a program in MATLAB. As of now, 1.0 is complete. The program is pretty much autonomous, but requires a few users inputs. I am trying to add a simple GUI interface to enter these paramaters and check off/on options. I know that MATLAB has a GUI format for new files, but I want to know if it is possible to add the GUI to a preexisting program.

Here is what I need the program to have:

a. a few check boxes that change values in the program from 'false' to 'true and vice-versa.

b. a few short fields that allow user entry

c. a start button that runs the program and plots graphs.

How Would you suggest I go about this?

Thank you so much,

-Alex

Comment: I would start with the [Matlab GUI guide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/bqz79mu.html#creating_guis), or one of the [dozens of Google hits on the subject](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=matlab+GUI).  Once you understand how to use Matlab GUIs, you may not need to ask this question...

Comment: @Oli is correct.  A simple .m file that wraps the rest will be a shortcut to this.  A simple GUI isn't hard to develop.  A small .m file will be able to get the parameters and call your program.  The only small issue is whether to pass the parameters in memory or save them to a file and have your program read that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor your program so that it exposes its main functionality as MATLAB functions that can be called from other places.

Some of these functions would perform the main computations taking as input the parameters you mention. Other functions would be dedicated to plotting the result.

Once you do that, designing a GUI to drive the program is as simple as calling the correct functions from the callback routines of the GUI components.

Comment: To say it needs to be refactored is a little overstating things.  A simple wrapper should do the trick.  Exposing the program internals is different from his 3rd (c) request - launch the program.

Comment: Thanks, I will add a wrapper ASAP.

Comment: @Iterator: By refactor I meant taking out interesting sections of code, put it in a function, and call the function instead of the inlined code. When prototyping in MATLAB, one tends to write everything in a script file, then starts reorganizing the program once done (at least that's how I end up working most of the time)... For example separate the code that reads and parses the data, from the logic of the program, and from the part that produces plots and reports.

Comment: @Amro: Got it, thanks for the clarification.  I used to do the one script, too, but eventually put different things in different .m files.  I just wanted to be sure it wasn't a recommendation to pursue intensive refactoring for a simple solution.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Start `guide` put all the buttons and fields you need (graphically) and bind the button to your functions.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is connecting the file (untitled.fig) to my program(eotvos20.m).

Comment: @Alex: Buttons, etc. work via callbacks, i.e. they are configured to just call specific functions when they're clicked.  You just need to hook up your functions.

Comment: Thanks, I will add a function wrapper around my main program!